# I want my nav to be fixed in a certain position while scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have navbar in the right side of my page, now I am setting "fixed" to the position property of the nav, but thta prevents me from seeing other items in the navbar while scrolling down, here is the photos so you can understand more, here is what I have now, and when I scroll down

[image]

Scroll down : ( you see that I can see clearly the setting item )

[image]

But what I want to achieve is something like this while scrolling down since Setting item is last item in my list :

[image]

I am using ReactJS and SASS to do this and here is my ReactJS code :

```
const MenuLeft = props => {
const menuItems = [
    { id: 1, item: "Données personelles", icon: faMale, isSelected: true },
    { id: 2, item: "Synthèse", icon: faFolderOpen, isSelected: false },
    { id: 3, item: "Historique", icon: faList, isSelected: false },
    { id: 4, item: "Analyse de portefeuille", icon: faFolderOpen, isSelected: false },
    { id: 5, item: "Description", icon: faFileInvoice, isSelected: false },
    { id: 6, item: "Documents", icon: faFolderOpen, isSelected: false },
    { id: 7, item: "Opérations", icon: faCogs, isSelected: false }
];

return (
    <nav className="co-menu-left">
        {menuItems.map(item => (
            <MenuItem item={item.item} icon={item.icon} isSelected={item.isSelected} />
        ))}
    </nav>
);
};
```

And here is my SASS file :

```
.co-menu-left {
    width:100px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: fixed;
    left:10px;
    top:85px;
}
```

Here is my items React code ( jsx ) :

```
class MenuItem extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isSelected: false
    };
}

changeBackColor() {
    alert("hello");
}
render() {
    return (
        <Grid onClick={() => this.changeBackColor()} container className="co-menu__backcolor">
            <Grid item xs={12} className="co-menu__icon pb-0">
                <div className="co-menu__icon--centered">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        icon={this.props.icon || ""}
                        size="3x"
                        className="co-menu__icon--color"
                    />
                </div>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} className="co-menu__text pt-0">
                <Text content={this.props.item} className="co-menu__text--color" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} className="pt-0" />
        </Grid>
    );
}
}

export default MenuItem;
```

Here is the sass I used for my child elements :

```
.co-menu {

&__backcolor {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: $black-rock;
    &:hover {
        background: $black-russian;
    }
}


&__icon {
    margin:0 5%;
    text-align: center;
    &--color {   
        color: $mischka;
    }
    &--centered {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
}

&__text {
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    &--color {
        color: $mischka !important;
    }
    p {
        margin-top:7px;
    }
}

}
```

I can provide with more code if needed.

I hope I can find some help, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello @TaouBen. You should just be able to change its height from '1000px' to '100%'?

Comment: @JackTempleman I tried but still same thing, I can provide you with more code,  I need help because it took me hours of searching.

Comment: By changing the height of the sidebar to 100%, you will be fixing it to 100% height of the viewport. You will then need to set the height of the inner elements to '12.5%' in order for 8 of them to fit in the sidebar.

Comment: Or as @segFault suggests, you could enable scrolling within the sidebar so users could scroll vertically to view the overflowing contents.

Comment: Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r0xdfets/

Comment: but the height of my child elements is more that 12.5% which caused me problem .. one item inside the other when I used this .. I can use some JS code if needed ..

Comment: it may help to provide more of the rendered HTML, at least a few levels of the container/parent elements.

Comment: Then you would need to enable horizontal scrolling. How else can you fit the child elements in? Even if you made the child elements smaller so they fit, at small screen sizes the elements would overflow (without using height percentage).

Comment: @segFault I will provide you with more code right now..

Comment: @segFault edited, if you need more code I will add

Comment: @JackTempleman I am trying to undestand your point, but I may be wrong, I am trying to set vertical scrolling as a last option, but what I want is when I scroll down in my window ( whole page ) the content of the nav bar is scrolled down too but stops when there is no more items. you can go to the landing page of the facebook and go to div-container where stories are shown, when I scroll down in the whole page, I am scrolling down into that div too but it stops when there nothing more in the bottom, did you undertsnad ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `absolute` positioning on the nav, e.g.

```
.co-menu-left {
    width:100px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:85px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vqt946L/2/)

Comment: If I do that, the position of my nav will change ( it will be positioned on the left because it is inside other div that have relative positioning ) , I need  to set it to fixed.

Comment: You could enable scrolling within the fixed nav element? but that might look messy... Another option might be to move the nav element into a parent container that encompasses the entire window.

Comment: but If I enable the scrolling within the fixed nav, my items will be seen just if the user scrolls down in the fixed element, Am I wrong ?

Comment: I can not move the element to another place, because I need to respect the code structure my team is following